# Xamarin DependencyService Get() method NULL when using wrapper

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have created a DependencyServiceWrapper so I can replace it in unit tests following the guide here: https://robgibbens.com/unit-testing-with-xamarin-forms-dependencyservice/

My wrapper is located in my Portable project and looks like this

```
public class DependencyServiceWrapper : IDependencyService
    {
        public T Get<T>() where T : class
        {
            // The wrapper will simply pass everything through to the real Xamarin.Forms DependencyService class when not unit testing
            return DependencyService.Get<T>();
        }
    }
```

Then my viewModel simply news this up in the constructor as shown below

```
public TasksListViewModel(Page page) : this(page, new DependencyServiceWrapper())
        {
        }

        public TasksListViewModel(Page page, IDependencyService dependencyService)
        {
            this.page = page;
            this.connectivityService = dependencyService.Get<IConnectivityService>(); 
            this.taskRepo = dependencyService.Get<ITaskRepository>(); // NULL HERE
            this.RowClicked = new Command<Guid>(OnTaskSelected); // NULL HERE
            this.RefreshList = new Command(RefreshTasks);
        }
```

Previously in my ViewModel I had

```
public IConnectivityService ConnectivityService => DependencyService.Get<IConnectivityService>(); // Returns correct object (so I know it's registered correctly).
```

Can anyone advise why I get NULL. When I call the wrapped service (above) I get NULL, yet doing the wrapped call directly from the ViewModel works fine.

Thanks,
David

Comment: What do you mean by "Can anyone advise why the wrapped Get call which works if I call directly from my ViewModel is returning NULL?"? Does the `Get` call work at any time? Are you sure you have got an implementation of `IConnectivityService` registered? Is the standard `DependencyService` working?

Comment: The DependencyService works fine as a property on the ViewModel directly, just not when I wrap it into another class.